# adding choices dynamically in django model based on 2-3 other models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model which has an intake field..

```
class University(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ....
    ....
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Course(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    university= models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING)
    ....
    ....
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class CourseDeadline(models.Model):
    intake= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    course= models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING)
    ....
    ....
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.intake)


class Coupon(models.Model):
    code= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    university= models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING)
    intake= models.ForeignKey(CourseDeadline,on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING)

    ....
    ....
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.code)
```

I would like to show intakes dynamically as a choice field based on selected university.something like

```
u= Universitiy.objects.get(id=university)
c= Course.objects.filter(university=u).order_by('id').first()
cd= CourseDeadline.objects.filter(course=c).all()
intake= models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=cd)
```

Is it possible through Models or Forms and this model is for django admin.

Comment: dynamic form can only be done through JS(AJAX). User ajax to check when user select value from selection then call api to update the other drop down

Comment: Yes, I tried populating in ajax.. But I am getting the error.. select a valid choice.. I have  a view that fetches a list of options like['A','B'] and in the ajax I am trying to populate them   ---  success: function (data) {        $.each(data, function(index, text){
              $('select[name=intake]').append(
                   $('<option></option>').val(text).html(text)
               ); 
            })                                                                          
    intake_choices= [('','......'),]
    intake= forms.ChoiceField(widget= forms.Select())